# Can Flask-Restful accept case-insensitive argument names?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

If I do this with Flask-Restful:

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('group', type=str, help='Please specify a valid group')
```

then the parser will accept an argument of `group=X` but not `Group=X` or `GROUP=X`.

Is there a way to make it be case-insensitive when taking argument names?

(The `reqparse.Argument` class has a parameter called `case_sensitive` but unfortunately that only makes the **values** case insensitive (by making them lowercase).  It doesn't affect the argument name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a different `Argument` class to the `RequestParser` that wraps the args in a case-insensitive `MultiDict` subclass.

```
class CaseInsensitiveMultiDict(MultiDict):
    def __init__(self, mapping=None):
        super().__init__(mapping)
        # map lowercase keys to the real keys
        self.lower_key_map = {key.lower(): key for key in self}

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key.lower() in self.lower_key_map

    def getlist(self, key):
        return super().getlist(self.lower_key_map.get(key.lower()))

    def pop(self, key):
        return super().pop(self.lower_key_map.get(key.lower()))


class CaseInsensitiveArgument(Argument):
    def source(self, request):
        return CaseInsensitiveMultiDict(super().source(request))

parser = RequestParser(argument_class=CaseInsensitiveArgument)
```

You can still have case-sensitive args by passing an `Argument` instance to `add_argument`, rather than keywords.

The `MultiDict` subclass implements just enough to be case-insensitive for the parser's use case, it's not suitable as a general implementation.